# Want bash script to get txt file all possible combinations

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have following characters, numbers and special characters:

```
012345789
!@#$%
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

I want a bash script that create a txt file that have all the possible 8 digit combination of above for example:

`aK@05B!8` and so on. Can you please suggest me a script?

Comment: Can each character be repeated in the resulting combination? If so, note that the resulting text file would be over 3PiB (pebibyte) large.

Comment: Yes but one character/ number can only be used maximum two times in one combination.

Comment: Please add that to your question. Make it easy for us to read the question by having everything clearly in one place

Comment: From your example (where the characters are in an arbitrary sequence), I suspect you intended "permutation", not "combination". See Wikipedia if you need to clarify.   In what language would your "script" be?   My rough calculation is that, if you restrict this to no repeats in the 8 chars, and get a million results a second, it runs for eight years. With repeats, at least an order of magnitude slower.   You might target 4 from 10 to get an algorithm, but your stated problem is infeasible.

Comment: I missed the "bash" tag in the title. In bash, the execution time would be measured in millennia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an illustration that demonstrates how to answer the question you've asked:

```
s='1 2 3 4 5'    # Space separated alphabet of characters

for a in $s
do
    for b in $s
    do
        for c in $s
        do
            printf "%s%s%s\n" "$a" "$b" "$c"
        done
    done
done
```

This code has an alphabet of only five characters, compared to your 66 (you've omitted `6` from your number range), and uses only three iterators rather than your eight. It generates 125 outputs:

```
111
112
113
114
115
121
122
...
555
```

Using your alphabet but still with only three iterators will produce 287496 combinations. You can determine the number of combinations by raising the number of characters in the alphabet to the power of the number of iterators. Here, for example, 5<sup>3</sup> = 125 and 66<sup>3</sup> = 287496, and your target requirement would be 66<sup>8</sup> ≈ 3.6x10<sup>14</sup> combinations.

Comment: Thanks I shall see how it will work in my case.

Comment: @Ajay It does however permit more repetitions than 2. It would be possible to filter them out, but the initial list would be gigantic (67^8): it would be better to generate the smaller list all in one shot. One algorithm for the two-dup might be to generate all the unique 7-char patterns, and then interpolate another of each char in the 8 possible positions (six between each pair of chars, plus one at front and back). Still needs the one-dup with eight unique chars as well.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant the "maximum of two" hasn't been added to the question so I've not worried about addressing it

Comment: @roaima  Good point. I'm still struggling with O(n?) for the base problem, but the whole requirement makes no sense.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant double the alphabet and allow no repetition by index

Answer (score 0):

Use this c++ program. it take too much time so you need patience

```
// C++ program to generate all passwords for given characters (length 8-10)

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
void generate(char* arr, int i, string s, int len)
{

    // base case
    if (i == 0) // when len has been reached
    {
        // print it out
        cout << s << "\n";
        // cnt++;
        return;
    }
 
    // iterate through the array
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
 
        // Create new string with next character
        // Call generate again until string has
        // reached its len
        string appended = s + arr[j];
        generate(arr, i - 1, appended, len);
    }
 
    return;
}
 
// function to generate all possible passwords
void crack(char* arr, int len)
{
    // call for all required lengths
    for (int i = 8; i <= 8; i++) {
        generate(arr, i, "", len);
    }
}
 
// driver function
int main()
{
    char arr[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','7','8','9','!','@','#','$','%','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    crack(arr, len);
 
    //cout << cnt << endl;
    return 0;
}

// This code is edited by RASAL RAHIM.
```

Comment: Why did you suggested a C++ program in place of the BASH request?